# How to start the ur modern driver in pos based instead of vel based

Tags: ros, ur-modern-driver, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is mentioned in the README of the driver that there is a way to switch between the two modes of executing the joint trajectory. However, how should one specify one rather then the other as default when deploying the driver?

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Victor Wu.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328003/how-to-start-the-ur-modern-driver-in-pos-based-instead-of-vel-based/) by [Victor Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40929/victor-wu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2019-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This would be the same as with other `ros_control` based `hardware_interface` drivers: by changing the configuration of which controllers are loaded and started vs loaded and stopped.

For the UR3 with `ur_modern_driver` that can be done with the `controllers` and `stopped_controllers` launch file arguments [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver/blob/fd2e38af745b9d471a4f9532be5f39e5d95fe405/launch/ur3_ros_control.launch#L20-L21):

> ```
> <arg name="controllers" default="joint_state_controller force_torque_sensor_controller vel_based_pos_traj_controller"/>
> ```

```
<arg name="stopped_controllers" default="pos_based_pos_traj_controller joint_group_vel_controller"/>
```

as you can see, by default the `joint_state_controller`, `force_torque_sensor_controller` and the `vel_based_pos_traj_controller` are loaded and started, and the `pos_based_pos_traj_controller` and `joint_group_vel_controller` are loaded but in the *stopped* state.

You'll want to change that such that `pos_based_pos_traj_controller` is loaded and started and `vel_based_pos_traj_controller` is loaded but stopped.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor Wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40929/victor-wu/) on 2019-07-09**:
Thank you. That will let me go back to the pos_based controller to carry on my work and try to learn how to use the vel_based controller. I am hoping that the vel_based controller can give me a smoother movement.